# Convert Analogue signal to digital

Tags: digital, analog

I am not sure if this is the place to post this type of question. If it is not I will delete.

At present I have 4 analogue cameras 'talking' to my DVR.

I want to unplug 1 of these cameras from the DVR and connect it directly to my PC.
Is there a typical analogue to digital converter I can use?

The analogue cables endpoint is a balun.

If this is not the correct forum then I would be grateful to be told what is the correct forum?

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information here. What sort of PC? Is it running Windows, OS X, Linux, or something else? Is the camera standard def or high def (or something else)?

Comment: @user1118321 Hi thanks for showing an interest.  The PC is windows 7 64bit.  The camera is analogue CIF

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about CIF, so I'm not sure where to point you, but hopefully the additional information will improve your chances of getting an answer!

Comment: @user1118321 indeed. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a [video capture device](https://www.google.com/search?q=video%20capture%20device) or a [capture card](https://www.google.com/search?q=video%20capture%20card). It will encode the analog video and audio into digital codecs (like H264 for video and AAC for audio, or other codecs depending on your needs and price range).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I knew I needed a video capture device but after searching myself through Google (before you posted your links) I could not find 1 for this specific case where the cable endpoint is a balun